# Start and stop the loop while button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, foreach

I am using the below code to start and stop the foreach loop execution. But start is working fine. I can't stop the loop execution while stop button click. Please help me to do this.

```
private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txt_rows.Text != "") {
        thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(update));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    //My logic here
}

private void btn_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_appstatus.Text = "Stop"; // Button click event not fired while run the loop
    lbl_appstatus.Update();
    lbl_appstatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

    if (thread != null && thread.IsAlive)
        thread.Abort();
}
```

Comment: Where is your "loop" ?

Comment: where is update ?? i think it should be PunchUpdate

Comment: I still don't see a loop or anything that needs to be aborted.

Comment: I think you might wanna look at this (maybe you just need a guideline):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx
notice that the tutorial mention about a boolean for terminating the thread's loop..

Comment: What is that `foreach` tag for?

Comment: This question is not clear. It's may be go to hold.  What you mean by start and stop? and where is foreach loop execution? and what is your requirement? and How many buttons there? etc....

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if you click twice or more on start button you loos your previous thread objects; Thus you should not create more than one thread.

Comment: I'm not so sure how that helps to answer the question? Maybe turn it into a comment?

Comment: Maybe his problem is when he click twice on start button.

Answer (score 0):

The "Start" and "Stop" clicks are separate requests to that codebehind. These use *separate* instances of you Page class, which usually means two separate "thread" variables (you didn't show the declaration).

So on the "Stop" click that `thread` value is always `null`.

For an "InProc" session, maybe it's possible to store that thread value in Session, so you can keep the value across requests.